# Juntar 2 PDF em 1 asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo 2 arquivos pdfs e quero juntar os 2 em um arquivo somente, meu método está da seguinte forma:

```
public async Task<FileResult> Teste(int id)
        {
            var objRelatorioTecnicoData = RetornoTecnicoAssinanteDataById(id);

            var modelPdf = MapperService.MapAsync<IncluirRelatorioTecnicoPdf>(objRelatorioTecnicoData).Result;
            await PreencherUfsMunicipiosPdf(modelPdf);
            GerarUfsMunicipios(modelPdf);
            GerarTecnicoUser(modelPdf);
            modelPdf.TemAutoTermo = modelPdf.AutoTermos.Count > 0;
            modelPdf.DataPublicacao = objRelatorioTecnicoData.DataPublicacao.ToShortDateString();

            const string contentType = "application/pdf";
            byte[] fileBytes = GerarPdf(objRelatorioTecnicoData, modelPdf);
            var numRelatorio = string.Empty;
            var length = fileBytes.Length;
            Array.Resize(ref fileBytes, fileBytes.Length + objRelatorioTecnicoData.DoctArquivo.Length);
            for(int i = 0; i< objRelatorioTecnicoData.DoctArquivo.Length; i++)
            {
                var count = (length + i);
                fileBytes[count] = objRelatorioTecnicoData.DoctArquivo[i];
            }

            if (objRelatorioTecnicoData != null)
            {
                numRelatorio = objRelatorioTecnicoData.NumeroRelatorio;
            }
            return File(fileBytes, contentType, "Relatoriotecnico_" + numRelatorio + ".pdf");
        }
```

Porem ele imprime somente o 2º pdf, ja fiz de várias formas e não consegui juntar os 2, alguem tem alguma solução para me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: nesse código não tem nenhuma informação sobre combinar dois pdfs, explica melhor por gentileza

Comment: tem, o primeiro é p fileBytes, o segundo é o objRelatorioTecnicoData.DoctArquivo, o filebytes gera o primeiro pdf corretamente, o objRelatorioTecnicoData.DoctArquivo gera o segundo  pdf corretamente,porem nao consigo juntar os 2.

Comment: ja tentei começar pelo ultimo, coloquei filebytes,length, porem da erro.

Comment: cara eu acho que não da pra simplesmente combinar os bytes, tenta ver alguma lib tipo o itextsharp